# Laravel migration to mix drops invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed

Tags: node-modules, laravel-mix

When I run yarn run dev it compiles without any issues, but when I run the yarn run prod I got the following error:

```
✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 21.47s

ERROR in /js/app.js
/js/app.js from Terser plugin
Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
Error [ERR_WORKER_INVALID_EXEC_ARGV]: Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at new Worker (node:internal/worker:194:13)
    at ExperimentalWorker.initialize (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js:149:20)
    at new ExperimentalWorker (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js:145:10)
    at WorkerPool.createWorker (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:44:12)
    at new BaseWorkerPool (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/base/BaseWorkerPool.js:127:27)
    at new WorkerPool (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:30:1)
    at new Worker (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:167:26)
    at getWorker (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:391:9)
    at /var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:494:41
    at next (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js:90:7)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js:93:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at throttleAll (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js:62:10)
    at TerserPlugin.optimize (/var/www/dashboard-v2/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:651:34)

webpack compiled with 1 error
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
root@fe7a5c6ae6f9:/var/www/dashboard-v2#
```

I have deleted all node_modules installed all from 0, updated all to the latest still the same. Any idea how to resolve this isue?

Comment: I had the same problem with current version of node.js (17.20). I downgraded to the LTS version (16.13) and it works again perfectly.

Comment: Thx will try this. I have created a new laravel 8 from out of the box and got the same error. Not sure why it treats as dependency where I can see all is at the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

Node v17.x is giving this issue.

I suggest you switch to v16. On Linux it's easy, you just reselect the older version on your system:

```sh
sudo n
```

It will show you the older versions on the system if any which you can switch to. If you don't find any v16 you'll have to manually install it.

See https://ostechnix.com/how-to-manage-nodejs-versions-with-n-in-linux/

Comment: what is `sudo n` ? Can you please fix it

Comment: @alexey_the_cat this is how you interact with n in linux, added reference in my reply

Answer (score -2):

Did try many things and one option was to revert node to v16 as suggested by **usernotnull**,  but wanted to find what is the real issue.

It seams that if it is php 7.4 or less then it try to load dependencies, when upgraded php to 8 and on cli too the error was gone.

Also upgrading from laravel 7 to 8, [need to update the dependencies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies).

After upgrade this is also a good to do so no cache or view left:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Since then all works and not geting the above error.